# Insufficient memory. First aids tried. Everything is tried! Pls help!

Tags: google-play-store, whatsapp-messenger, insufficient-memory, ram, micromax-a110

We have two phones with same problem. 
1) Micromax Canvas A110
1GB RAM,  4GB Internal,  8GB EXTERNAL SD CARD
Ice cream sandwich 4.04

LATEST PROBLEM:

On rebooting( turning the phone and switching it on again), all APPS disappear!!

Contacts disappear. All downloaded apps are gone! 
But their shortcuts are there on homescreens. When touched it says APP NOT INSTALLED.

Trying to download again is impossible. 
ERROR : INSUFFICIENT MEMORY...

A) Tried moving all Apps to INTERNAL SD CARD. (only two options show,  Internal storage &  internal SD card). 
Most apps are not movable. Show in Grey. Does not allow to move from internal.

B) Default write disk is EXTERNAL SD CARD

C) Tried clear cache. Tried clear data from Google PlayStore but it still does not allow to download!

2) MICROMAX CANAVAS A300 (Micromax Canvas gold) 
32GB inbuilt memory. No expandable storage in any external SD Card. 
I can't tell you how it has ruined my life..

Very much used to always cut paste apps,  pictures &  every other data to expandable SD card helps in Samsung Note 3 and other phones, an inbuilt restricted memory of 32GB still seemed ok. 
Only that apps don't use it!

I still move to 'Phone storage' from 'Internal Storage'. 
Because apparently 'Phone Storage' is better than 'Internal'.

But I'm still haunted by Insufficient storage. Insufficient space problems whenever I try to install a new app. I've to compromise and Uninstall a few apps and also run 360 to clean system junk files and residual files.

Pls help! I'm sick and tired of this! Badly need to have whatsapp messenger back in place for mom

Answer (score 0):

### For insufficient memory

**Disclaimer**: *Try at your own risk. I am not responsible for any data loss.*

Go to Settings > Apps.
* Select Google and Clear data (this clears the Google Search and Google Now Application data).
* Select Maps and Clear data.
* Select Chrome and Clear data (only if you have logged in to Chrome and made sure that all your bookmarks are synced to Google Servers).
* Select Google Play Services and Clear data.

### Disappearing apps

If the apps disappear, it may be because they are installed on the external SD card and may need more time to load.